# Laravel API Best Practice

Tags: php, api, laravel

I'm building API with laravel 5.1.

I have 3 section access: User, Admin, Super Admin.

I'm curious about the practice for handling the controller. Right now I make 3 different controller for each section. But sometimes I need to call same function inside the controller. Such as `Product:all()`.

Should I really make 3 different controller or i can use only 2 controller for the best practice?.

Comment: Do you check the user role with a middleware? Do you only call the same function or do you have to duplicate more than one line for each user role?

Comment: no. I'm not checking it with middleware. Because User section is access from mobile. My middleware only checking for the header auth and user token.

Right now i want to make admin API, but i just realize that Admin and Super Admin using almost same API except their authorization

Comment: Just to make sure: You have an API that should return all products. You have 3 routes/controllers for this, each for one role (`api.example.com/api/v1/user/products`, `/api/v1/admin/products`, `api/v1/super-admin/products`). And each route returns the exact same data set? Is that right?

Comment: yes. The difference between them only the header authorization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would just use one controller/one route `/api/v1/products` when the returned dataset is the same for all users (i.e. for basic users, admins and super admins).

I guess that each admin/super admin is also a user. So you should protect your `/api/v1/products` route with a middleware that just checks if the user is an authenticated user, because then he is allowed to access the data.

If there is some data other than products that can only be accessed by an admin/super admin, you should create another middleware for that. It is never necessary to create two or more controllers/routes for the exact same API.

Comment: do you have any better solution whats the best url should looks like? Right now i'm using: `api.example.com/api/v1/user` and `/api/v1/admin/` i'm afraid it will going to be a confusion betweeen `/user` and `/admin`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Looks like im going to make 2 controller instead. I just realize my User access almost different in every part for the request.